# How to edit 'my tags'?

Tags: support

I have been seeing this for a while now and I was wondering if it was possible to edit 'my tags' as seen in the screenshot.

[image]

Every time I click on the 'unanswered' tab in stack overflow, it automatically filters them by 'my tags'. I would like to know if there is a way to change 'my tags' so my unanswered tab is sorted by the tags I want it sorted by, rather than the two shown in the image.

The 'Favorite Tags' section of my preferences say this:

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow has changed since this answer and the Favorite Tags control does not seem to exist anymore. It is a useful question and it would be good to know how this now works currently!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Your tags" or "my tags" (yours not mines!) are actually just your favorite tags. To "edit" them, just add/remove tags from your favorites and (after you blame caching) it would change.

Comment: So clear my cache and 'my tags' should reflect my favorite tags?

Comment: @Developer_ACE caching is on SE side.

Comment: So how would I get past that? @Braiam?

Comment: You don't need to get "past" nothing. Just that sometimes, you just have to wait until SE invalidates the cache so it shows your current preference.

Comment: Ok. However, it's been like that for a while now... Do you know how often SE invalidates the cache?

Comment: @Braiam, can you please update your answer for the present version of SO?